# Past simple or Present perfect in this case

Tags: grammar

I'm not sure how to use tenses in some sentences.

> A:  Have you ever come to one of these seminars?
>
> B:  No, but I went to a similar seminar in Europe last year.
>
> A: **Have you learnt / Did you learn** a lot at that seminar?
>
> B: Not really, but I **met/have met** many interesting people **during** that week in November.

I an unsure whether I should use "*Have you learnt*" or "*Did you learn*”.

Is it okay if I use "*Have you learnt*"? I think he might learn something from the seminar which has an effect on the present moment.

And should I choose "*met*" or "*have met*"? Is it possible to use "*have met*" since there is "*during*" in the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the portions that you have highlighted,

> 1. **Did you learn** a lot at the seminar?
> 2. Not really, but I **met** many interesting people during that week.....

Are more appropriate than the alternatives.
The right tense to use here is *simple past*, as the events that occurred back then have no direct correlation to the present. 
Present perfect is usually used when those events have some connection to the present. 

You can look through a few examples of the difference [At this link.](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html)